# Is there any R package that supports fitting an HMM using multiple sequences of observations

Tags: r

Is there any R package that supports fitting an HMM using multiple sequences of observations? to the best of my knowledge depmixS4 does not support this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit multiple sequences of observations in the depmixS4 package with the argument ntimes.

Comment: thanks a lot . It's a pity that depmixS4's documentation is vague about it.